# python function to determine how statistically likely it is that a number belongs to a given list of numbers

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to find a function (in Python, ideally) that will tell me how 'similar' a number is to a given list of numbers.  The end goal is to find out which list a given number is more likely to be a member of.

For example, take the two lists:

```
a = [5,4,8,3,6,4,7,2] 
b = [9,5,14,10,11,18,9]
```

the function should take a new number, and tell me how similar it is to a given list.  For example lets assume a hypothetical 'isSimilar' function will return a percentage chance that a number could be a member of a provided list:

```
# 5 looks pretty similar to list 'a' but not list 'b'.
>>> print isSimilar(a,5)
.9

>>> print isSimilar(b,5)
.5


# 15 looks more similar to list 'b'
>>> print isSimilar(a,15)
.4

>>> print isSimilar(b,15)
.8


# 10 looks like it has roughly the same chance to be in both lists
>>> print isSimilar(a,10)
.41

>>> print isSimilar(b,10)
.5
```

Ideally this hypothetical function would take the standard deviation of the lists into consideration.  So, for example, in the following two lists:

```
a = [5,6,4,5]
b = [1,9,2,8]
```

the number '5' is more 'similar' to list 'a' than 'b' because the std deviation of the numbers in 'a' is much smaller.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are the .41 score calculated or just an made up number to illustrate a point?

Comment: What's the specific application? You may find a more complete answer to your question on the statistics Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

How about using an estimated pdf for both sets?

```
def get_most_likely_distribution_membership(value,d1,d2):
    nparam_density1 = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(d1) # can use a different kernel
    nparam_density2 = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(d2)
    x = np.linspace(-20, 30, 200) # maybe pre-define a range
    nparam_density1 = nparam_density1(x)
    nparam_density2 = nparam_density2(x)
    assert d1!=d2 

    if nparam_density1[np.where(abs(x-(value))==min(abs(x-(value))))].tolist() > nparam_density2[np.where(abs(x-(value))==min(abs(x-(value))))].tolist():
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

Essentially, we're saying that if a single value the is more probable in a distribution, it's probably from that distribution.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [5,4,8,3,6,4,7,2] # 1
b = [9,5,14,10,11,18,9] # 2
print(get_most_likely_distribution_membership(6,a,b))
print(get_most_likely_distribution_membership(10,a,b))
```

1 and 2, respectively.

Comment: Welch's T-test could be used to calculate the confidence of a match. `scipy.stats.ttest_ind`

Comment: right on @LegendofPedro,  We could assume the the distribution or use the underlying distributions to get a confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def isSimilar(a_list, member):
    m_count = a_list.count(member)
    return m_count / len(a_list)
```

Or perhaps using sets:

`set(a_list).intersection( set(b_list))`

which will return the intersection of the two lists, you could then count the resultant list and do some other maths.

Also consider using `difflib` if you are working with strings/sequences/etc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Docs on list.count():

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not exactly sure about the percentage thing. But, figuring out which list the number is more likely to belong to shouldn't be too difficult. I would just calculate the average difference between the number and all the numbers in the list. The closer the average distance is to 0, the more likely it is to be in the list.

```
  def whichList(self, list1, list2, someNumber):
        if self.averageDistance(someNumber,list1) < self.averageDistance(someNumber, list2):
            print "list 1"
        else:
            print "list 2"

  def averageDifference(self, someNumber,myList):
        sum = 0
        for num in myList:
            sum = sum + math.fabs(num-someNumber)
        return sum/len(myList)
```

Comment: Obviously, this doesn't deal with the case of equality. In that case, it would just print list 2. But you can handle that however you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Any 'percentage' would be subjective, but you could still use subjective numbers to rank. This approximates the list as normal distributions and samples from them to see the likelihood of drawing the number (in a discrete bin around it).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def isSimilar(x, A, N=10000):
    M, S = np.mean(A), np.std(A)
    test = lambda:  x - 0.5 <= norm.rvs(loc=M, scale=S) <= x + 0.5
    count = sum(test() for _ in xrange(N))
    return 1. * count / N

def most_similar(x, *args):
    scores = [(A, isSimilar(x, A)) for i, A in enumerate(args)]
    sorted_scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda (i, s): s, reverse=True)
    return sorted_scores[0][0]

A = [4,5,5,6]
B = [1,2,8,9]
C = [5,4,8,3,6,4,7,2]

most_similar(5, A, B, C) # returns [4,5,5,6]
```